# Top running processes - interpretation of Termux result

Tags: processes, termux

Post updating a bunch of apps, I noticed high battery drain and temperature. I ran `top -m 10` on Termux and the output is below

[image]
Going by the CPU usage, the first app is a big culprit and was killed (will study the change in performance later).

How do I interpret the fields in heading (line 800%CPU 107% user...) and in general how do I get help? (`top --help`only gives the options but not the description)

Comment: CPU on Linux is usually measured in 100% equals 1 CPU core.
So 800% means 8 CPU cores.

Comment: This means that processes in user space, doing ordinary things that don't require calls into the kernel, are using 1.07 CPU core equivalents cumulatively. You can also think about those numbers in terms of time, meaning a total of 1.07 seconds per 1 real time second of CPU time is spent doing unprivileged CPU instructions.

Comment: This [blog gives details](https://www.lifewire.com/linux-top-command-2201163)